# POST /projects/123/star.json returning 400 Bad Request

Tags: basecamp

Brought over from Git

Trying to add the new API URLs to the PHP Basecamp Client. Get stars and delete stars works fine, but POSTing throws a 400.

**Request**

> POST /1804401/api/v1/projects/234118/star.json HTTP/1.1

**Response**

> **400 BAD REQUEST**

---

Looks like it will work if I send the project_id as an argument in the payload.

**Request**

> POST /1804401/api/v1/projects/234118/star.json HTTP/1.1

**Request Body**

> {"project_id":234118}

**Response**

> HTTP/1.1 201 Created

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: @dirkk - it does not appear as though the API is working as it is supposed to. So I am trying to diagnose if it is something I am doing wrong, or something with the API.

Answer (score 0):

I checked our logs and I see your requests going through successfully. Could you try your `POST` again, with an empty request body?

Update: Aha! I see your requests receiving a 400 response - it's happening before they hit Basecamp. That could be due to a malformed request of some kind. Could you try to reproduce using `curl` so we can troubleshoot exactly what's occurring? Hard to tell from URL alone.

Comment: Tried again with same result: 
POST /1804401/api/v1/projects/4715366/star.json HTTP/1.1

Response:
Header: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Comment: Hi @JeremyKemper !

I'm facing same issue (iOS) while hitting the *star.json* API and I get a **403 (Forbidden)** response.

https://basecamp.com/1973733/api/v1/projects/4287844-mss-mobile-app/star.json is the URL I'm hitting.

The *HTTP Method* is **POST/DELETE** when I wanna **STAR/UNSTAR** a project, respectively.

Ideally, should get a **201 (Created)**.